# Apex class query error

Tags: apex

I am trying to write a query to get a lead's contact information back from a phone number.

The code is:

```
global class AccountRetrieval{

webService static String getAccount(String phone_number) {
List<Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();
for (Lead lead : Database.query('Select Id, Name, phone, email from Lead where phone like\"' + phone_number + '%\"')){
   leads.add(lead);
}

   String JSONString = JSON.serialize(leads);
   return JSONString;
}
}
```

The error I get is:

```
System.QueryException: line 1:56 no viable alternative at character '"'

Class.AccountRetrieval.getAccount: line 5, column 1
```

Comment: Replace \" with \' and try.

Comment: Also you need space after 'Like' in your query.

Comment: Put also  String.escapeQuote method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce this method to one line

```
global class AccountRetrieval{

  webService static String getAccount(String phone_number) {
    return Json.serialize([select id,name,phone,email from Lead 
                            where phone LIKE :phone_number + '%']);
  }
}
```

I'm a bit puzzled why you are searching `Leads` in a method named `getAccount` but I assume you have a valid business use case here